# как обрезать строку в php

Tags: php

как удалить 2 последних слова после слеша

вот исходная строка `'1/2/3/4few543/534ewf3'` нужно сделать  `'1/2/3/'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$str = '1/2/3/4few543/534ewf3';

$delimeter = '/';
$parts = explode($delimeter, $str);
$countOfParts = count($parts);

// variant 1
$deleteTails = 2;
$newParts = array_slice($parts, 0, $countOfParts - $deleteTails);
//$newParts = array_slice($parts, 0, -$deleteTails);  
echo implode($delimeter, $newParts);

echo "\n";

// variant 2
$lastPartIndex = $countOfParts - 1; // т.к. ключи массива нумеруются с 0;
$penultPartIndex = $countOfParts - 2;
unset($parts[$lastPartIndex]);
unset($parts[$penultPartIndex]);
echo implode($delimeter, $parts);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php 

$str = '1/2/3/4few543/534ewf3'; 

$pieces = explode("/", $str);

$output = array_slice($pieces, 0, -2);

foreach ($output as $k) {
echo $k,'/';
}

?>
```